# npm install azure-event-hubs node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, iot

I tried to set up a node.js to simulate inputs to an azure Event Hub.

A) when i tried to install thru:  》npm install azure-event-hubs
I got the warning message:

> > npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.

Does this mean it is still working? just a warningmessage?

B) As my susbequent node.js script failed to accept the connection string i copied from my Azure Event Hub:

Code:
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;

var connStr = 'Endpoint=sb://abrstrial.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DeviceAccess;SharedAccessKey=Npb.....................

> > (errors)

E:\Azure ML\LAB04\fitness_device\node_modules\azure-event-hubs\lib\client.js:92
    throw new ArgumentError('Connection string doesn\'t have EntityPath, or missing argument path');
    ^
ArgumentError: Connection string doesn't have EntityPath, or missing argument path
    at Function.EventHubClient.fromConnectionString (E:\Azure ML\LAB04\fitness_device\node_modules\azure-event-hubs\lib\client.js:92:11)
    at Object. (E:\Azure ML\LAB04\fitness_device\exercise.js:5:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

Would it be due to different access method to Azure classic vs ARM portal? or it is a node.js compilation problem?

Answer (score 0):

> npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported.
>   It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you
>   should switch to the one that's built-in.

[This SDK is currently in preview, and is maintained by Microsoft employees and external contributors in their free time. For offical SDKs please see:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-event-hubs)

- Event Hubs .NET SDK
- Event Hubs Java SDK

> E:\Azure
>   ML\LAB04\fitness_device\node_modules\azure-event-hubs\lib\client.js:92
>   throw new ArgumentError('Connection string doesn\'t have EntityPath,
>   or missing argument path');

The connection string will have the following format:

```
Endpoint=sb://[your event hub namespace].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[your policy name];SharedAccessKey=[key];EntityPath=[your event hub entity name]
```

You can add an entity like this:

[image]

And then use this entity's connection string.